# Maven Versions Plug-in Skipping Update Check

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

When I attempt to use `versions:use-releases` my release repository is marked as "disabled", meaning the snapshot dependencies do not get resolved to releases. I don't understand why the repository is considered disabled.

Here is the abbreviated debug output from the build:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteArtifactRepositories = [       id: snapshots
      url: http://maven.live.hostname.net/content/repositories/snapshots/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
,        id: company-nexus
      url: http://maven.live.hostname.net/content/groups/public/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[...]
[DEBUG] Looking for a release of promotion-test-central:promotion-test-central:jar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] artifact promotion-test-central:promotion-test-central: checking for updates from snapshots
[DEBUG] Reading resolution-state from: /home/tester/.m2/repository/promotion-test-central/promotion-test-central/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution-state to: /home/tester/.m2/repository/promotion-test-central/promotion-test-central/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Skipping update check for artifact promotion-test-central:promotion-test-central (/home/tester/.m2/repository/promotion-test-central/promotion-test-central/maven-metadata-company-nexus.xml) from disabled repository company-nexus (http://hostname/content/groups/public/)
```

I run a setup that mirrors requests to `central` to our Nexus instance, and also specifies a global snapshot repository too:

```xml
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>mendeley-nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://maven.live.chonp.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <url>http://maven.live.chonp.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>default</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
```

There exists a release and snapshot version of the dependency in question, and the repository works exactly as expected in all other respects.

Comment: @ZnArK - How does one do the XML syntax highlighting?

Comment: for xml you need to add the comment `<!-- language: lang-xml -->  
SO uses prettify, here's the README http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

This is also a great resource  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75019/187632

Comment: 1 up as I had the exact same problem and this answer worked perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your settings.xml file should be configured [as documented in the Nexus book](http://sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config.html). Your configuration wont work since it only partly overrides the super pom of Maven.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make much sense. Of course if I enable on nexus profile a single repo for both snapshots and releases it would work. But why should I do that? What's the point in looking for releases in the snapshot repository only?

Comment: The point is that you are mirroring EVERTHING (release and snapshots) into the public group and you need to enable them to come through. Unless of course you never want to use snapshots..

Comment: Well ideally I'd like to keep my snapshots out of the public repo, otherwise why bothering to have 2 repos? 

Anyway here the issue is the opposite, looking for releases in the snapshot repository. What I understand is that maven guys meant the snapshot repo to keep everything *plus* the snapshots, not snapshots only. Which is also fine with me if only it were a little more explicitly documented.

Comment: Thanks.. I was getting flabbergasted by the same problem and would have never arrived at this solution. Just wondering though , if Maven guys did not mean **snapshot repo to keep everything plus the snapshots** , then why ??

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this. I was able to get past it by doing:

```
    <repository>
        <id>my-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://nexus.corp.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

which was a departure from previously having:

```
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
```

This seems to happen when Maven looks up the metadata for your *current* artifact, and limits its search to only repos that could also contain that artifact.